# MPlayer benchmarking - realtime FPS counter

Tags: mplayer, real-time, benchmark

I was trying to use MPlayer as a simple benchmarking tools and I need it to show the real time FPS counter, either on the console or on the video playback itself. I googled around and I stumbled across `-benchmark` option but I don't see the information I required anywhere. I get something like this:

```
A:   6.9 V:   6.9 A-V:  0.000 ct: -0.039   0/  0  5%  8%  0.3% 0 0
```

Is there any way I can retrieve such information, though I prefer if it shows on the video playback itself. If Mplayer cannot perform this, is there any alternative that fulfill my requirements?